# CSS Animate dashed-border of div as progress bar with time that repeats

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a 2 pixel dashed boarder, and I would like to animate it so that it fills in with a different color over time until it is all filled in, and then would repeat over and over again.

I have a jsfiddle with the style that I have around my div

```css
.widget{
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px dashed #E4E6EF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
   test
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kqfd5jh9/

The height is fixed but the width isn't, it would depend on how many I have.

I am not to sure where to start or what method would be best to achieve this, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I cannot understand you requirements, must it be a progress bar of loading data? Or what? Do you want all border color change at the same time?

Comment: No its more like a timer, I just used progress bar as an example of what it would look like, I want the boarder to change color as time goes up to lets say 10 seconds, then restarts over and over.

Answer (score 1):

I attached a snippet that fulfills your requirements, border color will change infinitely every 10 seconds to green color. Just added an animation property on widget and the keyframes setup the initial color and ending color. Hope it helps.

For more information about CSS animations refers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

### Edit

As you requested, I made a working snippet that does what you want, I had to use an svg and javascript , to make it work. Hope it helps, the code is very straight forward.

You can see this for further research of how it works:

[stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray)

[stroke-dashoffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset)

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const border = document.querySelector('.widget rect#color');
  const borderLength = border.getTotalLength();
  const timeFactor = 4; // Highest number is fastest
  let borderOffset = borderLength;
  border.style.strokeDashoffset = borderLength;
  border.style.strokeDasharray = borderLength / 2;
  
  let initialTime;
  let isColorAnimationSetted = false;
  
  const animation = () => {
    // Set the frame time only first time
    if (!initialTime) {
      initialTime = new Date();
    } else {
      !isColorAnimationSetted && setColorAnimation();
    }
    borderOffset -= timeFactor;
    border.style.strokeDashoffset = borderOffset;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);
  };
  
  // We set the time for the color animation to match the progress animation to be completed
  const setColorAnimation = () => {
    const frameTime = new Date() - initialTime;
    const framesToEnd = (2 * borderOffset) / timeFactor;
    const timeToComplete = framesToEnd * frameTime;
    border.style.animation = `color-change ${timeToComplete}ms linear infinite`;
    isColorAnimationSetted = true;
  };
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);

};
```

```css
.widget{
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.widget svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

rect#color {
  stroke: transparent;
  stroke-width: 5;
  fill: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

rect#dash {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 6;
  fill: none;
  stroke-dasharray: 5,5;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40px;
}


@keyframes color-change {
  0% {
    stroke: red; /* Starting color */
  }
  50% {
    stroke: #00FF00; /* Ending color */
  }
  100% {
    stroke: red; /* Starting color */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="widget">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio='none'>
    <rect id="color" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="100%" />
    <rect id="dash" x="0" y="0" height="50px" width="100%" />
  </svg>
  <p>Test<p>
</div>
```

Comment: I meant that it changes color by going around the border, like a progress bar kind of. so like after 25% only the top would have changed color, the after 50% half of it, etc until 100% when it would restart.

Comment: Edited, hope it helps! @user2989367